# How do I update the year in a chrono DateTime instance?

Tags: datetime, rust, rust-chrono

How do I change the year in a `DateTime<FixedOffset>` instance (from the rust crate [`chrono`](https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/))?
That is, create a new instance of `DateTime<FixedOffset>` that copies the month and day from the old instance.

In other words, how would I complete the following code:

```rust
fn datetime_set_year(
  datetime: &DateTime<FixedOffset>,
  year: &i32
) -> DateTime<FixedOffset>
```

The code can ignore exceptional cases like leap days (if that is possible).

Comment: [`datetime.with_year (year)`](https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/trait.Datelike.html#tymethod.with_year)?

Answer (score 1):

The passed `DateTime<FixedOffset>` instance is taken apart to a `Date<FixedOffset>` instance and a `NaiveTime` instance. Then `FixedOffset.ymd` and `.and_time` create a new `DateTime<FixedOffset>` instance using the passed `year`.

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bd46479d6caf8ecb55cba9af1945f8f5)

```rust
fn datetime_with_year(datetime: &DateTime<FixedOffset>, year: i32) -> DateTime<FixedOffset> {
    let date: Date<FixedOffset> = datetime.date();
    let time: NaiveTime = datetime.time();
    let fixedoffset: &FixedOffset = datetime.offset();
    match fixedoffset.ymd(year, date.month(), date.day()).and_time(time) {
        Some(datetime_) => {
            eprintln!("fixedoffset.ymd() Some {:?}", datetime_);
            datetime_
        }
        None => {
            eprintln!("fixedoffset.ymd() None");
            datetime.clone()
        }
    }
}
```

---

Update: or use [`datetime.with_year(year)`](https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/trait.Datelike.html#tymethod.with_year) as recommended by @Jmb.

Doh!